# Adding ascending numbers to a rows of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named ROWID and I'd like to add ascending numbers to it... to be used as a PK. What script can I run that will just automatically just add numbers 1 through whatever? I know since its not an Identity column and seeded it wont increase with updates.

So basically I'm looking for a fill command that with just add ascending numbers.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword. More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

Comment: I am not aware that "autoincrement" is used in SQL Server.  Can you describe its use in this database?

Comment: Well is not difficult, you just add the AUTOINCREMENT to the usual primary key declaration, and the SQL Server will take itself care to assign the autoincrement id to the rows. I don't how is this exactly done ( either they do a query for the max id, or they store it somewhere) but it is not relevant to you. You can just use it as it is in the link I provided you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned this column is to be used as a Primary key so hopefully you wont have any duplicates in that column. Assuming this that you dont have any duplicates in this column the following query will work just fine.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
 (
  SELECT ROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWID ASC) AS RN
  FROM TABLE_NAME
 )
UPDATE CTE
SET ROWID = RN
```

And since you want this column to be sequential auto increment why not just add an identity column. Unfortunately you can make an existing column Identity column, So you will need to create another column with Identity.

Something like this..

```
--Drop the existing Column 1st

ALTER TABLE Table2
DROP COLUMN  ROWID 

--Create a new column and make it Identity column

ALTER TABLE Table2
ADD  ROWID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: If I did what would happen? I know I've had databases with dups in them and haven't seen an issue...

Comment: You cant make a column primary key if it has duplicates in it. A primary key creates a Unique Clustered Index behind the scenes to enforce uniqueness in a column. if you have duplicates in that column and try to create a primary key constraint on it . it will throw an error and command will never be executed.

Comment: realistically the reason I need a PK is the heap is so large when it runs a query. I'm trying to lessen the load a bit and figured the PK would help... but there are dups. What if I don't enforce identity? Thank an adding colums to the index will make the terabyte databse just too large so...

Comment: Then I would segguest to leave rowid column as it is an add an other column make that an identity, in above mentioned queries skip the 2nd one and just use the last query with a different column name.

Comment: So if a column doesn't have identity I shouldn't make it a PK due to duplicates. But if I have dups and identity comumn for PK reasons it ok?

Comment: There are only two things you need to make a column primary key, it must be not null-able and it must be unique, identity is an auto-increment feature which has nothing to do with primary key.